# Inserting the content to the colume in sqlite

Tags: c#

My sqlite table is like this

```
 content_id      content_no      content_1       content_2
  1               1:1             NULL            1:1 text
  2               1:2             NULL            1:2 text
```

Now i want to insert the contents to "content_1". Only is content_no matches to content_1's 1:1.

My insertion code is like this:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "insert into Content (content_1) values (?)";

 SQLiteParameter Field3 = cmd.CreateParameter();
 cmd.Parameters.Add(Field3);
 Field3.Value = node.InnerText;
```

But it is inserting the content like this

```
 content_id      content_no      content_1       content_2
  1               1:1              NULL           1:1 text
  2               1:2              NULL           1:2 text
                                 1:1 text       
                                 1:2 text
```

I dont want like this. The last 2 lines should move to first 2 lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (SQLiteTransaction SQLiteTrans = connection.BeginTransaction())
               {
                   using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                   {
                     cmd.CommandText = ("update contents set content_1 ='" + paraNode + "' where content_id ='" + Count + "'");


                       SQLiteParameter Field1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
                       SQLiteParameter Field2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
                       cmd.Parameters.Add(Field1);
                       cmd.Parameters.Add(Field2);
                       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
                   SQLiteTrans.Commit();
               }
```

Happy coding:)

Answer (score 2):

> I dont want like this. The last 2 lines should move to first 2 lines

You need **UPDATE** statement, not `INSERT` statement.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Content SET content_1 = @pcontent_1 WHERE content_id = @pcontent_id";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@pcontent_1", "1:1"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@pcontent_id", node.InnerText));
```

Where you need to pass the `content_id` and `content_1` to the query.

Comment: i used the update statement also. But i dont no what i have to use which are in single quote. cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Content Set content_1 = 'node.Innertext' WHERE content_no = '1:1'";

Comment: @PiggyChops, use parameters for that purpose as well

Answer (score 0):

You either have to `delete` previous content and `insert` new one or,

just have to fire `UPDATE` query on existing content.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Update** is more appropriate in your case, but you need to provide the primary key also, not only the content_1